# SpeechSynthesis not working in CEF - chromium embedded framework

Tags: angular, webkit, chromium, chromium-embedded, speech-synthesis

I have an Angular app that reads "Hello world." as soon as it starts up. If I open my app and run it within Chrome, it works fine and the audio is played. However, my app is meant to be run embedded within another application using CEF - Chromium Embedded Framework. When I run my application from there, the audio does not play. 
I'm using the standard SpeechSynthesis included with webkit.

Has anyone experienced this issue? If so, how did you get around it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the `--enable-speech-input` flag.
2. Generate Google API keys: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys
3. > The 50 requests cap with no option for a paid plan is unfortunate.
   >   http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=14914